# Convergence to zero in $L^2$ by this sequence of continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

I have been struggling with the following exercise:

Let $\{f\}_n\subseteq C[a,b]$ be a cauchy sequence w.r.t the $L^2$ norm, s.t. for every $[c,d]\subseteq [a.b]$ we have $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_c^d f_n(x)dx=0$. Prove that $\int_a^b(f_n(x))^2 dx\to_{n\to \infty}0$.

This exercise isn't intended to be solved with any measure-theoretical tools. In Particular, it is given in a context where $L^2 [a,b]$ is defined to be the Hilbert-completion of $C[a,b]$ w.r.t.  $L^2$ norm.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Denote the inner product of $L^2$ by $\langle,\rangle$.  Can you show that $$\int_c^d f_n(x) \, dx \to 0 \implies \langle f_n,\phi \rangle \to 0$$ for each $\phi \in L^2$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Thank you for your very helpful hint. It put me on the track to the solution without giving too much away :). Much appreciated

Comment: Glad to help. A lot of times a gentle nudge is all that is needed.